# ASP.Net Linq to read database is not working

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, linq

Hi I have this link sentence what am I doing wrong?
FYI. This is an error after debugging.

```
 Dim categories = Aggregate pgmAccess In rvdDB.PgmAccesses 
   Where pgmAccess.OperatorID = RData.UserName 
   Join menuDef In rvdDB.MenuDefs On menuDef.ProgramName Equals pgmAccess.Program 
   Order By menuDef.MenuID 
   Select menuDef.ProgramDescription 
   Distinct Into ToList()
```

Error message

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Method 'System.Object
>   CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' has no
>   supported translation to SQL.

__

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object,
>   Boolean)' has no supported translation to SQL.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Method 'System.Object
>   CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' has no
>   supported translation to SQL.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 16:         Dim rvdDB As New RVDDataClassesDataContext Line 17: 
>   Line 18:         Dim categories = Aggregate pgmAccess In
>   rvdDB.PgmAccesses Where pgmAccess.OperatorID = RData.UserName Join
>   menuDef In rvdDB.MenuDefs On menuDef.ProgramName Equals
>   pgmAccess.Program Order By menuDef.MenuID Select
>   menuDef.ProgramDescription Distinct Into ToList() Line 19:  Line 20:
>   categories.ForEach(AddressOf MakeButton)
>
> Source File: C:\Users\pieterv\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\RVDMenu\RVDMenu\MenuFrm.aspx.vb    Line: 18
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> > [NotSupportedException: Method 'System.Object
> >     CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' has no
> >     supported translation to SQL.]
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitMethodCall(SqlMethodCall mc)
> >     +576409    System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +2146    System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression
> >     exp) +8
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitMethodCall(SqlMethodCall mc)
> >     +115    System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +2146    System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitExpression(SqlExpression
> >     exp) +8
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect
> >     select) +46
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select) +20
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +1024
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a) +13
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +457
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source) +8
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitJoin(SqlJoin join) +21
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +979
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source) +8
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect
> >     select) +27
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select) +20
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +1024
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a) +13
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +457
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source) +8
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect
> >     select) +27
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select) +20
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +1024
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a) +13
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +457
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source) +8
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect
> >     select) +27
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select) +20
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +1024
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a) +13
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +457
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source) +8
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.VisitSelectCore(SqlSelect
> >     select) +27
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select) +20
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node) +1024
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(ResultShape
> >     resultShape, Type resultType, SqlNode node, ReadOnlyCollection`1
> >     parentParameters, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations) +588
> >
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query,
> >     SqlNodeAnnotations annotations) +155
> >
> >     System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
> >     query) +132
> >
> >     System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
> >     +35    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +7675130    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1
> >     source) +61    RVDMenu.MenuFrm.LoadCategories() in
> >     C:\Users\pieterv\Documents\Visual Studio
> >     2013\Projects\RVDMenu\RVDMenu\MenuFrm.aspx.vb:18
> >     RVDMenu.MenuFrm.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> >     C:\Users\pieterv\Documents\Visual Studio
> >     2013\Projects\RVDMenu\RVDMenu\MenuFrm.aspx.vb:12
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
> >     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> >     includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> >     +627

Comment: Do you know what part of the line is throwing the exception? And the places where you are comparing objects, are they the same type, and does SQL know how to compare them?

Comment: I am sorry I am quite new to linq

Comment: What are the types of OperatorID and UserName?

Comment: Operator is a string from a table. Username is a variable

Comment: RData.UserName is also a string? Also what are types of enuDef.ProgramName and pgmAccess.Program ?

Answer (score 2):

From your error:

> Method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' **has no supported translation to SQL**

This means that you are doing an object comparison that SQL does not know how to perform.

The places I see that you are doing this comparison are:

- `Where pgmAccess.OperatorID = RData.UserName`
- `On menuDef.ProgramName Equals pgmAccess.Program`

You need to check what the datatypes of those properties are. Remember that SQL only knows how to compare common datatypes, like strings, ints, doubles, etc. It does not know how to compare datatypes that you create.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue RData.Username had to have .tostring now it works. Thanks @Yuriy Galanter